# Two calls inside a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I am a relatively new programmer.

I would like to learn why the quick_sort() is called twice recursively. According to my understanding the last line will not be executed.

This line should not be reachable: `quick_sort(array, pi + 1, high)`

```
# Function to perform quicksort
def quick_sort(array, low, high):
  if low < high:
  
      # Find pivot element such that
      # element smaller than pivot are on the left
      # element greater than pivot are on the right
      pi = partition(array, low, high)
  
      # Recursive call on the left of pivot
      quick_sort(array, low, pi - 1)
  
      # Recursive call on the right of pivot
      quick_sort(array, pi + 1, high)
```

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: It will be reached when / after the first recursive call returns.

Comment: Why do you think the last line is not reachable?

Comment: Since the `# Recursive Function on the left of pivot` will be called before it and the function will go to the top?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I was trying to understand quick_sort as give here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/

Comment: @0stone0 when `quick_sort(array, low, pi -1)` is called wouldnt the function go back to the top?

Comment: 'Yes', in the recursive part, but afte rthat finished (withtout the `return` you've probably forgotten) the original (first) function would just continue, and hit the last line.

Comment: @0stone0 how is that finished? for example we have an `array = [4, 7, 2, 1]` how will the first part be finished

Comment: Recursion doesn't "rewind" the current function. It just acts as a completely separate process. If you call function `b()` from `a()` then you still have the exection of `a()` which waits for `b()` to finish. Recursion does not deviate from that - only you are calling the same function: `r()` calls `r()`. We could label them "one" and "two" to differentiate them. Which would give the same situation as `a()` and `b()`. However, at the end of the day, they would still be the different calls of the same function

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you that makes sense, I tried to print values and see how it goes. I think I get it somewhat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive calls work no differently than simple function calls.

Consider this function `f`, which makes two calls, one to function `a` and one to function `b`:

```py
def f(n):
    if n > 0:
        a()
        print(n)
        b()

def a():
   print('  a')

def b():
   print('  b')

f(7)
```

When we call function `f`, it will first make the call `a()`, then when that call has finished, it will make the call `print(n)`, then when that call is finished, it will make the call `b()`.
Output:

```
  a
7
  b
```

There is no distinction between recursive calls and non-recursive calls. A function call is always just a function call; a recursive call is just a function call in which the called function happens to have the same name as the calling function.

Here is an example:

```py
def f(m, n, depth=0):
    if m < n:
        mid = (m + n) // 2
        f(m, mid, depth+1)
        print('  '*depth, mid)
        f(mid+1, n, depth+1)

f(0,15)
```

When we call function `f`, it will first make the call `f(m, mid, depth+1)`, then when that call has finished, it will make the call `print('  '*depth, mid)`, then when that call is finished, it will make the call `f(mid+1, n, depth+1)`.

Output:

```
       0
     1
       2
   3
       4
     5
       6
 7
       8
     9
       10
   11
       12
     13
       14
```